# Smooth curve that connects two points on a sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I am trying to prove that there is a smooth curve that connects two points on a sphere.
I want to prove this by using the Implicit Function Theorem.
(I know a lot of other ways, but I want to practice this way).
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could find a smooth function $f$ which satisfies $f(0,0,1)=0$ and $f(0,0,-1)=0$ and then claim that the solutions of the simultaneous equations $f(x,y,z)=0$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ define a nice curve. After all, by definition, the solutions lie on the unit sphere.  Does the implicit function theorem justify asserting that the solutions define a nice curve (1 dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$)?